# How does one access embedded solution files in a PCL class

Tags: c#, json, winrt-xaml, portable-class-library, win-universal-app

I'm trying to read PCL content file that I'm adding with the resource. the ideal use case for this is a REST service mock where I want to host a few json files for testing the Network services. I want to be able to read these json files as an alternative if the server is not available so what do I do to be able to achieve this?

both the json files and the NetworkService class are within the PCL. assume no other solution is relevant

this is what I tried

- dragged the mock json files and folders into the solution
- set Build Action -> Content
- set Copy to Output Directory -> Copy if Newer

This is the part of the NetworkService fallback code

```
var uri = new Uri("ms-appx:///mock/users/" + UserID + "/GET.json");
var file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(uri);
```

I get a System.IO.FileNotFoundException when I try to run this code. any ideas what I could be doing wrong? I tried the [EmbeddedResource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10963781/how-to-read-a-resource-file-within-a-portable-class-library) approach and that didn't work either.

Comment: Let me know if you need me to add more information about my problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an EmbeddedResource method that kinda workedfor the moment, I will upvote/mark a better answer involving Build Action > Content as that is a cleaner approach to handling this problem. the solution is presented in one of the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10963781/how-to-read-a-resource-file-within-a-portable-class-library/20446442#20446442)

```
// the below approach is essential to getting the right assembly
var assembly = typeof(TestClass).GetTypeInfo().Assembly;

// Use this help aid to figure out what the actual manifest resource name is. 
// can be removed later
string[] resources = assembly.GetManifestResourceNames();

// Once you figure out the name from the string array above, pass it in as the argument here.
// . replaces /
Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("TestMockJson.Mock.TestFile.Json");
var sr = new StreamReader(stream);
return sr.ReadToEnd();
```