# Exception while trying to read file usin PCLStorage from PCL project

Tags: .net, xamarin, portable-class-library

I am trying to get file from `PCL` project using `PCLStorage` as below. I am using Xamarin in Visual Studio 2015 Professional.

```
IFile file = await FileSystem.Current.GetFileFromPathAsync("file\path");
```

But I am getting exception as:

> System.NotImplementedException: This functionality is not implemented
>   in the portable version of this assembly.  You should reference the
>   PCLStorage NuGet package from your main application project in order
>   to reference the platform-specific implementation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add the PCLStorage NuGet to both your PCL and your platform specific project.

So if you have the following solution:

```
PCL
Android
iOS
```

You would need to add it to all of them:

```
PCL
    PCLStorage
Android
    PCLStorage
iOS
    PCLStorage
```

Why? Because the NuGet uses the bait and switch technique, where the PCL contains a simple facade with the bait. At runtime this gets switched out with platform specific implementation.

Comment: Thank you, exception gone, but GetFileFromPathAsync returning null, even though I have valid file in the location

Comment: I am trying to read file which I have added in my PCL project, not from local storage, Is that possible or not?

Comment: Yeah, but it is not related to PCLStorage plugin.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10963781/how-to-read-a-resource-file-within-a-portable-class-library